# My css grid layout doesn't fill its container on chrome. What's causing the loss of a fraction of a pixel?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-grid

The markup below works as expected on firefox (paragraph is 980px), but not on chrome (paragraph is 979.94px). Does anyone know how to prevent this from happening?

codepen example: https://codepen.io/isaacsgraphic/pen/jOVrrMO

```css
body {
  width: 980px;
  background: #99c;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  background: white;
}

.content-wrap {
  grid-column: span 12;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="content-wrap">
    <p>Example paragraph which is 979.94px, not 980 like the row it's within</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

here's a longer example which shows how this problem breaks my column layout on chrome: https://codepen.io/isaacsgraphic/pen/yLVJGqp

Comment: well, who will really notice the 0.06px of difference?

Comment: @TemaniAfif apparently the flexbox layout I have within it notices haha. I'm getting 3 columns in chrome and four columns in firefox, so it does translate to a real issue.

Comment: so share your real layout and let's try to fix it

Comment: @TemaniAfif I've added a more detailed example so you can see the issue I'm having with the columns. https://codepen.io/isaacsgraphic/pen/yLVJGqp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is a rounding error in chrome. It is possible to recreate the problem with any layout which creates a recurring number sub-pixel fraction for column widths (like 3 or 12 column layouts with 980px), whereas numbers of columns which divide the width easily like 5 or 10 work without issues. The same issues can be caused by grid-column-gap numbers which don't divide nicely.

The simplest fix is to make sure the layout pixel width divides neatly into 12 (6 and 3 work too actually, since chrome can handle one or two decimal places)

```css
body {
  width: 984px;
  background: #99c;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 18px;
  background: white;
}

.content-wrap {
  grid-column: span 12;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="content-wrap">
    <p>Example paragraph which is fits the full width of the row it's within</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe it is because of the different fonts different browsers use?

Comment: I don't think so, no. I tried setting everything to Arial, and even removing the paragraph entirely. Content-wrap is still the wrong size. I also tried removing all spaces between tags in case it was an issue like the common extra spacing issue with inline blocks.